# How to get the coordinates of a drawn box in OpenLayers?

Tags: coordinates, openlayers-3, rectangles

I am a novice to OpenLayers, so sorry for an obvious (and perhaps dumb) question, for which I found different approaches for solutions, but none working. Tried this and that, a dozen different suggestions ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19899/openlayers-get-coordinates-from-polygon), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836676/how-to-get-coordinates-of-a-polygon-in-openlayers), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018893/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-a-polygon-in-openlayers3-on-draw-end), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726734/open-layers-3-how-to-create-listener-for-a-modify-interaction/24835176#24835176), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129271/get-coordinates-of-drawn-feature-in-openlayers)) but in vain.

Basically, I want to pass the coordinates of a drawn rectangle to another webservice. So, after having drawn the rectangle, it should spit me out the four corners of the bounding box.

What I have so far is the basic OL layers example for drawing a rectangle:

```
    var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});


    vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#ffcc33',
                width: 2
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 7,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
                })
            })
        })      
    });



    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            vector
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
            zoom: 4
        })
    });



    var draw; // global so we can remove it later
    function addInteraction() 
    {
        var value = 'Box';

        if (value !== 'None') 
        {
            var geometryFunction, maxPoints;
            if (value === 'Square') 
            {
                value = 'Circle';
                geometryFunction = ol.interaction.Draw.createRegularPolygon(4);
            } 
            else if (value === 'Box') 
            {
                value = 'LineString';
                maxPoints = 2;
                geometryFunction = function(coordinates, geometry)
                {
                    if (!geometry) 
                    {
                        geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
                    }
                    var start = coordinates[0];
                    var end = coordinates[1];
                    geometry.setCoordinates([
                    [start, [start[0], end[1]], end, [end[0], start[1]], start]
                    ]);
                    return geometry;
                };
            }

            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: source,
                type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (value),
                geometryFunction: geometryFunction,
                maxPoints: maxPoints            
            });

            map.addInteraction(draw);               
        }
    }


    addInteraction();
```

Now, what comes next? What is a good way of extracting the bounding box?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to asign a listener to the draw interaction. Like so:

```
draw.on('drawend',function(e){
alert(e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/c4o4put8/)

Comment: Ah great! Thanks so much. Interesting however that the fiddle does work in Safari, but not its implementation on my side - which on the other side does work in Firefox and Chrome (all Mac)...

Comment: It is an official ol3 example(http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html) , I have just add the listener. It is strange indeed it doesnt work on safari. I dont have safari so I can not test it. Glad to help